# Difficulty loading target platform for eclipse RCP

Tags: windows, eclipse, ssl, rcp, target-platform

I am transfering my data from an old notebook to a new one. I have copied my eclipse folders and also the JDKs directly to the new notebook. The RCP project was checked out of Git on to the new notebook.

When I start eclipse and try to reload the target platform, I get many PKIX or 'host not reachable' errors. It runs for around 30 minutes and completes with errors. Considering that I simply copied the whole JDK, including `cacerts`, I don't understand why certificates cannot be found.

I double-checked by running the same action on the old notebook on the same network and it completes quickly and with no errors.

The IT dept claim that there is no block on the new notebook.

What might I be missing? What else could I do to gather more information?

Comment: If you installed, rather than just unpacked, the JDK on the original machine, can you try the same on the new one?

Comment: @nitind I simply copied the whole JDK folder from old to new. I am not aware that it needs to be installed but I will try installing it on Monday. I'll try any suggestion at the moment :-/